# Python3 SQL Update not committing

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-3.x

I have the following Python3 code:

```
def updateDB(databaseLoc, post_id, new_class):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(databaseLoc)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    vals = [new_class, post_id, ]
    curs.execute('UPDATE POST SET CLASSIFICATION=? WHERE POSTID=?', vals)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

which is called occasionally with

```
if js[0]['data']['children'][0]['data']['ups'] > 2000:
    print(post_id, "made it")
    updateDB('retrieved_data.db',1,post_id)
```

However, even after the update and the commit, when I go into the database, nothing has changed (classification is still set to the initial value 0). I have tested the SQL string manually and it works fine.

I have comparable code for insertion that works fine:

```
def pushToDB(databaseLoc, posts):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(databaseLoc)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    for p in posts:
        vals = [p.id, p.title, p.s, p.time, p.day, "", p.first, p.second, p.image, 0, ]
        try:
            curs.execute('INSERT INTO POST VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',vals)
        except:
            pass
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Is there an additional step that needs to be taken for a Python3 update? I have looked through the documentation and it doesn't specify anything additional, but then it only mentions update [once](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions) and just glosses over it. I have also found very little on update examples in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for the function is:

```
def updateDB(databaseLoc, post_id, new_class):
```

But you appear to be calling it with:

```
updateDB(databaseLoc, new_class, post_id)
```

Resulting in trying to update the post where `POSTID = 1` every time, which is probably not what you wanted.